# Cannot install ffmpeg on centos 6

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I tried to install ffmpeg on centos 6, but I got some dependency error like this:

```
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: x265-libs-1.9-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_3_0_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libx264.so.142()(64bit)
       Available: libx264_142-0.142-20_20140406.2245.el6.x86_64 (atrpms)
           libx264.so.142()(64bit)
       Available: x264-libs-0.142-4.20140423gite260ea5.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           libx264.so.142()(64bit)
       Available: x264-libs-0.142-7.20140728gitaf8e768.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           libx264.so.142()(64bit)
       Available: x264-libs-0.142-11.20141221git6a301b6.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           libx264.so.142()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libopenjpeg.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.1(CDIO_CDDA_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libass.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: libavdevice-2.6.8-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.1(CDIO_PARANOIA_1)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am using vultr vps as a cloud server and follow this tutorial:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos

Comment: Do you want to download all rpm packages manually for ffmpeg? If you want to install it manually. You can download all rpm packages from rpm.pbone.net.Download it into one folder and run # rpm -Uvh *.rpm.Because You already got all rpm packages list for ffmpeg

Comment: What's the problem with yum install ffmpeg ?

Comment: I just ran into this also, following instructions from https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55814 .. without the nux repo installed, `yum install ffmpeg` gives me 'No package ffmpeg available.'.  I have epel, extras and updates repositories enabled (visible via `yum repolist`).  @Rocky Liu did you ever get this working?  I really don't want to have to build from source if I don't have to (once I start installing own-build libraries for the dependencies I'm bound to run into dependency hell sometime in the future)

Comment: Progress.  I noticed in my output, and yours above, 'el7' is appearing, despite us both running CentOS 6.  It's because the nux repo is selecting el7 packages that lead to the inconsistency.  Perhaps you accidentally followed the 'for CentOS 7' part of the vultr.com guide you linked to.  I did the same thing, the advice in the forum I linked to above was only for el7, once I used the right repo, and cleaned yum cache (actually `rm -rf /var/cache/yum`) then `yum install ffmpeg` resolved el6 packages and there are no conflicts.